# How to Instantiate Python class in another Python class constructor?

Tags: python

I have a python class called PowerControl where the constructor instantiates another class called PowerControlA. Is it possible to instantiate PowerControl in such a way that I can treat the PowerControl object as PowerControlA object? Currently I am instantiating PowerControlA as a self.A of PowerControl.

EDIT: Currently this is the instantiation of PowerControl class. I would like the PowerControl Object to act as either PowerControlA or PowerControlB once it is instantiated and a parameter is passed in.

```
class PowerControl:

def __init__(self, type="SN"):
    if "SN" in type:
        print("A")
        self.pwr = PowerControlA()
    else:
        print("B")
        self.pwr = PowerControlB()
```

Comment: please add code.

Comment: See all the many existing questions on inheritance vs composition (/ 'is-a' vs 'has-a'). We can't know unless you tell us what `PowerControlA` is (that's a terrible name, please rename it and show us its code so we know what it does). *"Currently I am instantiating PowerControlA as a self.A of PowerControl"* => currently you're using composition.

Comment: What's different between a PowerControlA and a PowerControlB? This seems like the kind of thing where each A and B 'is-a' PowerControl, and PowerControl has either a `staticmethod` or a patched `__new__` that constructs the right one.

Comment: PowercontrolA and PowercontrolB have different method definitions depending on what hardware I am using.

Comment: Does `PowerControl` do anything *except* wrap an instance of either `PowerControlA` or `PowerControlB`? Perhaps you just want a factory function like `def power_control(kind): return PowerControlA() if kind == "SN" else PowerControlB(). (You can also make `PowerControl.__new__` into such a factory.)

Comment: PowerControl does not do anything except wrap either PowerControlA or PowerControl B. Can you explain what a factory function is?

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about inheritance vs. composition. This of this as either an "is-a" relationship or a "has-a" relationship.

If `PowerControl` inherits from `PowerControlA`, then `PowerControl` "is-a" `PowerControlA`. That's inheritance.

```
class PowerControl(PowerControlA):
    # stuff
```

If `PowerControl` instantiates `self.A = PowerControlA()`, then `PowerControl` "has-a" `PowerControlA`. That's composition.

```
class PowerControl(object):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        self.A = PowerControlA(*args, **kwargs)  # maybe

    # stuff
```

Which one you actually want to use is impossible to say without the problem being better specified.

Comment: I expect to be able to delete this answer if/when ANovice provides a better-defined question, but for the question as-asked this is as good an answer as exists!